# Do something once in a loop

Tags: ruby

So I have a script that checks for HTTP status every minute, if it's not 200 (OK) I will send an email saying something came up. The problem is how can send an email just once until the status changes (and then send an email again). I don't want to spam it every minute as loop goes. Thank you.

Here's my loop:

```
loop do
  if foo_response_status == false || bar_response_status == false
    send_email
  end

  puts foo_response_status.kind_of? Net::HTTPSuccess
  puts bar_response_status.kind_of? Net::HTTPSuccess
  puts Time.now

  sleep 60
end
```

Comment: Keep a state variable external to the loop that tells you when the service is already known to be down.

Comment: Maybe create a flag, which denotes, that the email has already been sent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using a variable declared outside of the loop, you can keep track of the previous status. This code checks whether new_status and old_status are the same; if so, it uses `continue` to skip the rest of the code in the loop.

```
old_status = false
loop do
  new_status = foo_response_status == false || bar_response_status == false

  next if new_status == old_status

  send_email if new_status == false

  old_status = new_status

  puts foo_response_status.kind_of? Net::HTTPSuccess
  puts bar_response_status.kind_of? Net::HTTPSuccess
  puts Time.now

  sleep 60
end
```

Comment: This IS the solution, neat and easy to understand. Thank you.

Comment: Ehm... there is no `continue` in Ruby. Maybe you meant `next`.

Comment: @steenslag fixed it, thank you! i'm working on a c# project and sometimes i jumble this vs self, next vs continue, etc ^-^'

Comment: In Ruby, there's almost never a good reason to test `something == false`. Just use `something` or `!something` with `if` or `else`.

Comment: @EricDuminil when modifying the asker's code to make it work, i try to make as few changes as possible to keep the solution clear. that being said, i think `!response_status` implies "i don't have a response status" whereas `response_status == false` implies "the status of my response is `false`." i agree that the use-cases for `something == false` are rare, but it isn't inherently inferior, imho.

Answer (score 0):

Use `break`

```
loop do
  if condition === true
    break
  end
end
```

This will cause the loop to quit looping.

In your case, it would be something like

```
if foo_response_status == false || bar_response_status == false
  send_email
  break
end
```

This will stop the loop after it sends the email. Note, this will not prevent the loop from running again if the script is re-executed (for example, in a cron)

Comment: these could be written with `until` as well.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it was very helpful. @eiko gave an actual solution.